# tensorflow recogtion object problem trained model

Tags: java, tensorflow

I'm creating a program which recognises an object, but I have some problem.
I use this code:

```
 File file = new File("Java.jpg");
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
   imga.setImage(image);


        String  modelpath= "C:\\Users\\AngruAdminAlex\\Documents\\inception_dec_2015";

  float verison=(float) 1.0;
                System.out.println("Opening: " + modelpath);
                modelselected = true;
                graphDef = readAllBytesOrExit(Paths.get(modelpath, "tensorflow_inception_graph.pb"));
                labels = readAllLinesOrExit(Paths.get(modelpath, "imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings.txt"));

           File file1 = new File ("Java.jpg");
          String imagepath="Java.jpg";
                System.out.println("Image Path: " + imagepath);
                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file1);


        //read image

        System.out.println("Reading complete.");
            byte[] imageBytes = readAllBytesOrExit(Paths.get(imagepath));
byte data[] = imageBytes;
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("buffer.rawfile");
out.write(data);
out.close();
            try (Tensor image1 = Tensor.create(imageBytes)) {
                float[] labelProbabilities = executeInceptionGraph(graphDef, image1);
                int bestLabelIdx = maxIndex(labelProbabilities);

                System.out.println(
                         String.format(
                                "BEST MATCH: %s (%.2f likely)",
                                labels.get(bestLabelIdx), labelProbabilities[bestLabelIdx] * 100f));

results.setText(  String.format(
                                "BEST MATCH: %s (%.2f likely)",
                                labels.get(bestLabelIdx), labelProbabilities[bestLabelIdx] * 100f));
        }
    }
```

When I use pre-trained model inception v3, all is okay, but when I use my trained model, I'm having error:

```
Opening: C:\Users\AngruAdminAlex\Documents\1.10

Image Path: C:\Users\AngruAdminAlex\Pictures\Test\20180907_213807.jpg
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NodeDef mentions attr 'dilations' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]>; NodeDef: module_apply_default/InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](module_apply_default/hub_input/Sub, module_apply_default/InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
    at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Native Method)
    at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:130)
    at org.tensorflow.Graph.importGraphDef(Graph.java:114)
```

Link for model: [model](https://nofile.io/f/wTgk1xCFpx2/inception_dec_2015.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How train  inceptionV3 for this code**

1. In  code change:

   ```
   Tensor result =  s.runner().feed("DecodeJpeg/contents",image).fetch("softmax").run().get(0))
   ```

   to

   ```
   Tensor result = s.runner().feed("DecodeJpeg/contents", image).fetch("final_result").run().get(0))
   ```
2. Download Tensorflw native libs from [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/tensorflow/libtensorflow_jni/1.6.0/libtensorflow_jni-1.6.0.jar)
3. Third step is unpack .jar like .zip and copy lib file in your project folder.
4. Just  get retrain.py from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py)
5. Open command prompt and enter command :

   ```
   python (path to retrain.py)  --image_dir (path to image) -- output_graph (path to graph files(.pb) -- output_labels(path to label(.txt)
   ```
6. Find .pb file rename it to label.pb and use in code

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link where a similar issue has been raised :

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/4093

Seems like you may have to update Tensorflow to 1.8 or later.

Comment: I try it but it dosen`t help :

Comment: I will get : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Operation named [input] in the Graph
 at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.operationByName(Session.java:356)
 at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.parseOutput(Session.java:365)
 at org.tensorflow.Session$Runner.feed(Session.java:131)
 at

Comment: Reading the log, I see that there is an error in understanding the input. Could you verify if the graph defined is correct and that you are sending the correct input to your model. It might happen that you may have changed your input's name or something like that?

Comment: I'll try! But i think it isn't work becouse i try use a 1.0-1.10 retrain sripts!!

Comment: There have been some changes in the 1.10 version of Tensorflow. If I understood your comment correctly, I think perhaps check with all the function calls in the new format and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Okay i'll reinstall tensorflow to 1.8.0 at train model !!